# Umbraco content tab error / mixed up document types

Tags: sql-server, umbraco

Using Umbraco 6.0.0 – I have no idea how this happened, but I'm trying to the bottom of it so I can either fix it or chalk it up as a learning experience.

Most of the content nodes are giving me this error:

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_cmsPropertyData_cmsPropertyType_id". The conflict occurred in database "UmLLWebDev", table "dbo.cmsPropertyType", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.`

Screenshot of the error: http://cl.ly/image/2t373f0r163I

The other weird thing that happened was all the properties from one of my child document types have 'moved' to the parent document type. I have no idea how this happened. i.e. I had several fields in a child Document Type called 'samples' and now these fields appear in its parent 'Master'.

Looking for suggestions on how to even go about investigating the problem because at this point I feel like I need to start over. My only lead for a cause is a batch sql script I use that backs up / restores the Umbraco database for deployment purposes.

Comment: This happened to my after renaming document properties. Should have remember that always bad things happen when renaming things in Umbraco! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

We have just experienced this problem too.

We solved it by deleting the `umbraco.config` file in the `app_data` folder. You may also need to recycle the app pool in IIS or by modifying the `web.config` file.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, although I had to recycle (touch web.config) at the same time as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to my comment before: "This happened to my after renaming document properties."
Deleting the renamed properties and re-adding them again solved the problem. I can see the nodes in Umbraco.

Comment: Had a similar encounter ... after restoring dev DB from production, I forgot that the property I've created in dev was (of course) no longer there. But somehow the browser still had the reference cached. So both @jebastian-j and your answer pointed me to the solution. Simply saving the document type (custom property was gone) and than adding it again...

Comment: @mecograph glad this answer could help you. Long time since my Umbraco days :)

Answer (score 1):

> **We've faced this problem & SOLVED it by just saving the modified
>   document types.**

**Note:**
*We've NOT removed Umbraco.config & NOT recycled the app pool.*